# How do I access to ListView from the adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have a custom `ListView` with my own adapter. I'm handling the click on a `Button` in my  `ListView`'s item, and I want the `ListView` to become invisible on this click.

I have no idea how to get access to the `ListView` from the adapter.

```
public class ScheduleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ScheduleListItem> {

    /*...*/
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(id, null);
        }
        final ScheduleListItem o = items.get(position);
        if (o != null) {

        /*...*/         

            Button details=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btn_details);
            details.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //HOW TO MAKE (R.id.lv_schedule) TO BECOME INVISIBLE HERE?
                }
            });
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: i thought the whole point of having an adapter is to decouple logic from ListView.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

`ViewGroup parent` holds reference to the parent of the `View` returned by `getView()`, which in your case is your custom listview.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    ...
    details.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            parent.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); // or View.GONE
        }
    });
    ...
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Instead of this you can pass the reference of your Listview through constructor of adapter and store that in local Listview variable. You can use this for access your Listviews method.Like this

```
public ViewPackagesAdapter(Activity mActivity, ListView cmgListView) {
        this.mActivity = mActivity;
        this.mListView=cmgListView;
    }
```

Now access Activity's Listview through mListView..

Answer (score 1):

In my case GridItemClickListner didn't worked for some reason. I access the **Gridview from Adapter class** using this

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          ((ClockGridView) v.getParent()).performItemClick(v, position, v.getId());
                         (OR)
           ((ClockGridView)parent).performItemClick(v, position, v.getId());
   }
 });
}
```

"ClockGridView" which extends "GridView" Class.