# Disabling GridView scrolling

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

I have a `GridView` of more than 10 rows. That is a reference chart so the user is unable to scroll manually. The `GridView` should be scroll down in a particular time period. What I have to do for that? Is it possible to make a `GridView` with only smoothscroll? One more Question i have is that.
how can we access gridview from adapter class.?

Comment: i havnt tried anything because i dont know what i have to do..

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the disabling of gridview scroll by

```
gridView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){ 
@Override 
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
   { 
    if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){ return true; } 
     return false; } });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `AlarmManager` to schedule that time period  for a method like that:

```
public void bringListDown(){
        int position = yourGridView.getCount();
        yourGridView.setSelection(position);
    }
```

This gonna bring your gridView to the bottom;

Comment: Never tried but, i THINK you can access it by the getview() of the adapter

Comment: take a look a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10910638/get-access-to-listview-from-its-adapter