# How to return adapted ListView from inside Adapter class

Tags: android

I have set an adapter to a list view

```
mListView.setAdapter(mListView)
```

How do I return this list view from inside the adapter class?

For example

```
mListView = this.getListView()
```

Comment: Now sure your question makes sense. Generally you set an Adapter from an Activity or Fragment. You are passing the data to the adapter. So a list, for example. Since you are passing that data to the adapter, it stands to reason that you already have that data in the Activity or Fragment. Why are you trying to pass views back and forth?

Comment: I'm trying to get a reference to the list that is being adapted to... I think maybe this post answers my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10910638/how-do-i-access-to-listview-from-the-adapter